# Javascript passing functions to other functions

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain the role of the 'unless' function and what the arguments 'test' and 'then' store?

```js
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) then();
}

function repeat(times, body) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
  unless(n % 2, function() {
    console.log(n, "is even");
  });
});
// ▹ 0 is even
// ▹ 2 is even
```

Comment: You can see what arguments are passed to it, and it only has one line in the body. What don't you understand?

Comment: Its same as `if(n%2===0){ console.log(n, " is even")}` but can be used for more than one case

Comment: Thanks all , its this line that throws me if (!test) then();.   Is this saying if test is false call then();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unless` here is merely syntactic sugar -- it makes your code readable. All it does is take two arguments: `test`, which is a value you want to test, and `then`, which is a function that you want to execute.

`unless` says "if the test is not truthy (i.e. `!test` evaluates to `true`), execute `then`."

You could lose the `unless` function and do this instead:

```
repeat(3, function(n) {
  if (!(n % 2) {
    console.log(n, "is even");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`unless` looks like a `syntacting sugar` here

it can be replace with simple condition block:

```
if(!(n%2)){
    console.log(n, "is even");
}
```

`then` in `unless` holds referenece to `function` which can be later invoked by `then()`

Answer (score 1):

Here unless function **check condition for odd & even number and print only even numbers**.

```
unless(n % 2, function(){
    console.log(n, "is even");
})
```

the first parameter means `test` get value `n % 2`.

the second one `then` is `function` which prints number in log.

in simple way

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
       console.log(i, "is even");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. I think the example in the book is illustrating how functions can be passed to other functions. Many thanks